# How Can I customize Spark Chart?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I copy spark sample from arsenal.
But I can't edit it.
Here's my spark chart.

[image: spark_image_click_here.]

And Here my code.
I want to show x-axis but i can't solve this.

### mainfragment.java

```
public class ConeFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_profile_c1, container, false);
    SparkView sparkView = (SparkView) view.findViewById(R.id.sparkview);
    SparkView sparkView1 = (SparkView) view.findViewById(R.id.sparkview1);
    adapter = new RandomizedAdapter();
    sparkView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter1 = new RandomizedAdapter();
    sparkView1.setAdapter(adapter1);


    public static class RandomizedAdapter extends SparkAdapter {
    private final float[] yData;
    private final Random random;

    public RandomizedAdapter() {
        random = new Random();
        yData = new float[5];
        randomize();
    }

    public void randomize() {
        for (int i = 0, count = yData.length; i < count; i++) {
            yData[i] = random.nextFloat();
        }


        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return yData.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return yData[index];
    }

    @Override
    public float getY(int index) 
    {
        return yData[index];
    }
}
```

And My XML here.

```
    <com.and.wodness.spark.SparkView
        android:id="@+id/sparkview"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:spark_lineColor="@color/colorProgress"
        app:spark_lineWidth="3dp"
        app:spark_scrubEnabled="true"

        app:spark_animateChanges="true"/>

    <com.and.wodness.spark.SparkView
        android:id="@+id/sparkview1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:spark_lineColor="@color/colorDarkRed"
        app:spark_lineWidth="3dp"
        app:spark_scrubEnabled="true"
        app:spark_animateChanges="true"/>
```